# loading a script with xhr and run it

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to load a script dynamically, but its not working, what am I doing wrong here?

```
<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =       this.responseText;     }   };   xhttp.open("GET", "haromd.js", true); xhttp.send(); };
loadXMLDoc();
</script> 

<script type="module" id="demo"></script>
```

The external script file only contains the script that goes into the module type script tag.
When the same script is in the script tag by without xhr it works/runs without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new  script element when you receive the content for it.

Modifying text in an existing script tag does not execute it but when a new script element gets inserted in DOM it will execute

Simple example

```js
const get_code = (msg) => `console.log('${msg}')`;

// try inserting in existing script element
document.getElementById('existing').textContent = get_code('Existing script tag');
console.log('Nothing prior in console')

// create new script element
const scr = document.createElement('script')
scr.textContent = get_code('New script tag')
document.body.append(scr)
```

```html
<script id="existing"></script>
```

Comment: actually it runs now even with adding it to existing tag:
https://adambernath.com/lotto/lotto7.html
How do I add a delay to it so it loads after the page is completely loaded? I want to separate it off of the main loading process and execute it after that is already finished for some seconds.

Comment: Create the element and do `scr.onload = function(){ /* run code*/)`

Comment: i mean obviously not with settimeout

Comment: Use new  script element load event

Comment: any other way than onload? that happens exactly when the page is loaded

Comment: That;s why you do it with new element